# perl - redirect system command to a file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, unix

I have this perl code below, basically want to loop through these 2 files. Then call a bash script (it takes the file and a delimiter as arguments and it prints out multiple lines) and then save all output from that command into a new file (with filename having '_processed' tacked on the end).
What is wrong with the below syntax (at the moment it just creates a blank file)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my(@files) = (
"fixedtt.txt '|'",
"delimd2iffpipe.dat '|'"
);
for my $i (0 .. $#files) {
    my($filename) = split /[\s]+/, "$files[$i]", 2;
    my($name, $type) = split /[\.]+/, "$filename", 2;
    open (MYFILE, '>'."$name".'_processed.'."$type");
    system("sh myBashScript.sh $files[$i]");   #I want to write the entire output of this command to a file
    close (MYFILE); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you open and close `MYFILE` without printing to it? Do you think that the `system` statement is writing to that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect the output of a terminal command by preceding it with `> <file name>`.  Ergo:

```
system("sh myBashScript.sh $files[$i]");
```

Becomes:

```
system("sh myBashScript.sh $files[$i] > file.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused with how perl writes to files. Your `open` and `close` on the `MYFILE` handle will only create an empty file. `system` does not do anything to that file within perl. (Though I cannot say what your sh-script does with it).

Some pointers:

- You are using the indexes of `@files` instead of the elements, which
  reduces readability for no reason, since the indexes themselves are
  not used anywhere.
- You are using `split` to extract file name and extension, and I
  assume there's a reason for that. However, there's no need to set
  LIMIT to 2, since you are only ever using the first one or two
  elements from that split.
- When you only have one character (or character class, e.g. `\s`), the
  brackets are not needed. So, use `\s` instead of `[\s]`.
- It is recommended to use the three-argument [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with a
  lexical file handle.
- Capturing output (to stdout) is done with [backticks or qx()](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/).
  [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) only returns the return value of the system call. [dunsmoreb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672118/dunsmoreb)
  is correct that you can simply redirect in the shell to create the
  file, but this is how it's done inside perl.

If I were to guess, I'd say you were trying to write the output of the bash script to the file you are attempting to open, in which case you should do:

```
my @files = (
    "fixedtt.txt '|'",
    "delimd2iffpipe.dat '|'"
);
for my $args (@files) {
    my ($filename)    = split ' ', $args;
    $filename =~ s/\./_processed./;
    open my $fh, '>', $filename or die $!;
    print $fh qx(sh myBashScript.sh $args);
    close $fh; 
}
```